# Error executing help manual pages on Fedora 25 for all kind of man pages

Tags: linux, fedora, sed, command, man

```
[user1@testMachine ~]$ lsb_release -a

LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:cxx-4.1-amd64:cxx-4.1-noarch:desktop-4.1-amd64:desktop-4.1-noarch:languages-4.1-amd64:languages-4.1-noarch:printing-4.1-amd64:printing-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Fedora
Description:    Fedora release 25 (Twenty Five)
Release:    25
Codename:   TwentyFive

[user1@testMachine ~]$ man wget
sed: can't read 2>/dev/null: No such file or directory
sed: can't read |: No such file or directory
sed: can't read less: No such file or directory

man: command exited with status 2: sed -e '/^[[:space:]]*$/{ N; /^[[:space:]]*\n[[:space:]]*$/D; }' | (cd <fd 3> && LESS=-ix8RmPm Manual page wget(1) ?ltline %lt?L/%L.:byte %bB?s/%s..?e (END):?pB %pB\%.. (press h for help or q to quit)$PM Manual page wget(1) ?ltline %lt?L/%L.:byte %bB?s/%s..?e (END):?pB %pB\%.. (press h for help or q to quit)$-iMSx4 -FXR MAN_PN=wget(1) sed s/\([[:space:]]\+[0-9.\-]\+\)$/\1/;s/\([[:space:]]\+[0-9.\-]\+[[:space:]]\)/\1/g;s/|/|/g;s/^\([-+]\+\)/\1/ 2>/dev/null | less)
```

Even lot of help commands are not working, and showing the same error page.

Comment: What does `type man` say?

Comment: @mattdm $ type man     
man is /usr/bin/man

Comment: Oh — is this Fedora Atomic, or Fedora Cloud Base? `grep NAME /etc/os-release`

Comment: $ grep NAME /etc/os-release 
NAME=Fedora
PRETTY_NAME="Fedora 25 (Workstation Edition)"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:fedoraproject:fedora:25"

Comment: You should try  to reinstall the man-pages as suggested here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252530/how-to-install-man-pages-on-centos + what @SvennD is saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do `export MANPAGER=less`, check that `/usr/bin/man wget` works after this and if so look very carefully around your RC files for overrides for MANPAGER and PAGER.

Comment: I removed export PAGER configuration from .bashrc and after rebooting its working now, awesome finding.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to reinstall the man package :

```
yum reinstall man
```

The error you are seeing makes me scared ... 2>/dev/null would send error messages to /dev/null (basically gone) Only very little good reasons to do this.

Have you checked `which man` and checked if it was a binary ?